# Determine whether an object is subclass of another class

Tags: ios, swift

I have some experimental code. But ultimate target is findType() should print/return true if the obj is of type 'parent'

```
class Car {}
class RacingCar:Car {}
let raceCar = RacingCar()

func findType(_ obj: Any, parent: AnyClass) {
    print(type(of: obj)) // RacingCar
    print(parent) // Car
    print(type(of: obj) == parent) // false
//  if obj is parent {
//      print("true")
//  }
}

findType(raceCar, parent: Car.self)
```

How can this be achievable?

---

With template suggestion,

```
    func isTypeOf<T>(_ obj: Any, parent: T.Type) {
    if obj is T { // true
        print("true")
    }
}

isTypeOf(raceCar, parent: Car.self) // worked

func getType(parentClass: AnyClass){
    isTypeOf(raceCar, parent: parentClass)
}
getType(parentClass: Car.self) // this dont work.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use generics to get the type:

```
func findType<T>(_ obj: Any, parent: T.Type) {
    print(type(of: obj)) // RacingCar
    print(parent) // Car
    print(type(of: obj) == parent) // false
    if obj is T { // true
        print("true")
    }
}

findType(raceCar, parent: Car.self)
```

Alternatively, you could pass in a `parent` object directly, then it would look like this:

```
func findType<T>(_ obj: Any, parent: T) {
    print(type(of: obj)) // RacingCar
    print(type(of: parent)) // Car
    print(type(of: obj) == T.self) // false
    if obj is T {
        print("true")
    }
}

let car = Car()
findType(raceCar, parent: car)
```

Comment: Thanks. I need the first solution. However, why parent.Type did not work but T.Type works? in is operator. if (obj is parent.Type) gives error.

Comment: There's a subtle difference between a `Type` and a `class`. When you use `is` you can only pass a `class`, because you're not checking if it `is a Type`, but rather, `is it a subclass of`. `AnyClass` is a typealias for `AnyObject.Type`, it's not actually a `class`.

Comment: But this did not work!

func isTypeOf<T>(_ obj: Any, parent: T.Type) {
 if obj is T { // true
  print("true")
 }
}

isTypeOf(raceCar, parent: Car.self) // worked

func getType(parentClass: AnyClass){
 isTypeOf(raceCar, parent: parentClass)
}
getType(parentClass: Car.self)

Comment: It doesn't work because `AnyClass` is a `Type`, it's not a `class`. You can't use `AnyClass` with this function. `AnyClass` is a typealias for `AnyObject.Type`, but for `isTypeOf` you would need to pass `AnyObject.self` for the function to work, but that will always return `true` (since all `class`es are of type `AnyObject`). If you're receiving something as `AnyClass` you may need to cast it somehow using `as?`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just put:

```
raceCar is Car
```

That will return true.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2885064-type) you could use `type(of:)`

> Returns the dynamic type of a value.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> You can use the type(of:) function to find the dynamic type of a
>   value, particularly when the dynamic type is different from the static
>   type. The static type of a value is the known, compile-time type of
>   the value. The dynamic type of a value is the value’s actual type at
>   run-time, which can be nested inside its concrete type.
>
> In the following code, the count variable has the same static and
>   dynamic type: Int. When count is passed to the printInfo(_:) function,
>   however, the value parameter has a static type of Any (the type
>   declared for the parameter) and a dynamic type of Int.

```
let type = type(of: value as Any)
print("'\(value)' of type '\(type)'")
```